# How to get here() to work with R markdown/Quarto

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

Hoping for some help - I have been banging my head for a few hours and I can't find a solution. I am trying to optimise a workflow which involves sourcing a script from a Quarto file (I imagine this would be the same for an R markdown file). If I run the actual script using `here()` to load csv files, it works perfectly and sets the root directory as:

```
here() starts at /Users/Jobs/2023/project_x
```

Which is where the R project file is located.

But if I source that same script from within a Quarto file it sets the root directory to one up from the folder containing the .qmd file, and prevents the csv files from being able to be read:

```
here() starts at /Users/Jobs/2023/project_x/Analysis/code
```

The .qmd file is located at:

```
here() starts at /Users/Jobs/2023/project_x/Analysis/code/rmd
```

Is this expected behaviour and can I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
here::set_here("/Users/Jobs/2023/project_x")
```

in a .qmd code chunk seems to work and keep all paths using here() intact in the source script, but I don't think it's ideal as I still need to specify an absolute path in the first instance.

Open to other suggestions...